# Stop image from caching in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caching

I am trying to complete the random quote generator on FreeCodeCamp. I pretty much have it but i decided i wanted to go one step further and change the background image with the button as well. I believe the background img is being cached from the very first call where the background img is originally set. Therefor every time i click the button the browser is essentially reloading the cached img instead of revisiting the site and pulling a new img.

The source i am using is just a site that returns a different image every visit.

I have tried adding a time stamp to the end of the url and the site just throws a invalid address image at me.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="mainDiv">
     <div class = "row text-center">
      <div class = "col-xs-12 well" id = "quote">
      The quote will go here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row text-center">
      <div class = "col-xs-12">
        <button id = "getQuote" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Get Quote
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html> 

body{
  background-image: ;
}
#mainDiv{
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://source.unsplash.com/random")');
  $.getJSON("http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json", function(json){
    $("#quote").html('"' +json.quote + '"<br> - ' + json.author);
  });
  $("#getQuote").on("click", function(){
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://source.unsplash.com/random")');
    $.getJSON("http://quotes.stormconsultancy.co.uk/random.json", function(json){
      $("#quote").html('"' +json.quote + '"<br> - ' + json.author);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp won't work because it is a 302 redirect, and the client-side script cannot intercept the 302 redirect, it is resolved automatically and you cannot do anything about that. You can read 302 headers on the server side though. You can try getting the image in your server, have it resolve the 302 and respond with the correct url.

If you are using the API you can try using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=32d223323",
  cache: false,
  success: function(result){
     $('body').css('background-image', 'url("' + result.urls.full + '")');
  }
});
```